# PL/pgSQL COPY variable FROM STDIN

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.6

I have the following script:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    i INTEGER;
BEGIN

    i := 5;

    COPY public.mytable (id, name) FROM stdin;
    i   abc
    \.

END $$;
```

I run the above script using psql. I want to take the value from the variable `i` and use it in the `COPY` command. How can I do this in PL/pgSQL? Can \echo be used?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable with dynamic SQL:

```
EXECUTE format('COPY %I FROM ''/path/file''', i);
```

But you cannot use `COPY ... FROM STDIN` in PL/pgSQL, because there is no standard input in a function.

Comment: Can \echo be used?

Comment: No, because that's a psql command, so you cannot use it in SQL or PL/pgSQL.

Comment: I'm using psql to run that script. Example: psql --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:port/dbname < filename.sql

Comment: Yes, but your function cannot use that. If you want to `COPY FROM STDIN`, you have to write client code.